# How Firebase Analytics handle session duration for background activity (mp3 player)

Tags: android, ios, session, firebase, firebase-analytics

I understand how Firebase Analytics counts session duration if application in foreground, but what if my application gives some services to user (playing mp3) which I want to count as a session ? Is it counting background activity by default or I should add something to code ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytics is looking at the time the user spends *in* your app, which means that (for Android) an Activity is visible on screen.  Anything happening in a service or in the background does not count as usage.

If you want to record time spent playing music, you can create your own custom events to track that, then export your data to BigQuery to derive a summary of that behavior.

Comment: Do I right understand that it was calculated in other way for Google Analytics ? I'm pretty sure that it calculated including an activity time in background.

Comment: Is it possible to use events like a ping (while playing in background). Will getting new events by Firebase (every 1 minute) counts as activity and provide more correct information about session time?

Comment: I don't know the answer for GA, but sending an event will not affect user engagement calculations in Firebase Analytics.  Those are entirely based on whether the app has an activity in the foreground or not.